# How much space is needed for a North America openstreetmap server?

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap

I am currently trying to implement an openstreetmap server for just North America. I am getting the data for North America from geofabrik. I have tried numerous times to load the data, and every time, after waiting several hours, the import process is cut off with some kind of out of space error. I am running on Ubuntu, and every time I check the space, I have more than half of my space still available. I don't know if the import process just requires a lot of space or something like that. I am currently working with about 70 GB of space.

For reference, I am following this tutorial to set up an OSM server:

https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/

And I am getting hung up on this step:

`osm2pgsql -d gis --create --slim  -G --hstore --tag-transform-script ~/src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.lua -C 2500 --number-processes 2 -S ~/src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style ~/data/north-america-latest.osm.pbf`

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi. Have you considered an option to use OSM providers? If yes, why not using them. Any particular reason? I'm in evaluation process of whether to set up my own server or use a provider.

Comment: I have not looked at any other providers, just because I was following the OSM guide posted on the switch2osm website, which recommended using geofabrik.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, the switch2osm pages also suggest [third-party providers](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-an-all-in-one-solution/).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am in the exact same situation, trying to run this on an Ubuntu instance @ AWS and the instance just dies despite 1TB space

Answer (score 1):

> the import process is cut off with some kind of out of space error.

You'll need to provide a few more details in order that people will be able to help diagnose the problem.  However, at first glance:

- Try it with a smaller extract first to make sure the process works.  The switch2osm guide suggests Azerbaijan because that's relatively small.  Maybe try just one small US state?
- 70Gb may be too low.  I have a tile server that "nicely fits" on a 100Gb SSD, and that covers the British Isles (1.0Gb of .pbf).  You are trying to load 7.8Gb of .pbf.
- Given you have more memory, you may want to revise your osm2pgsql command line to use more cache.